# Is Stack Overflow now the C/C++ student homework helpdesk?

Tags: discussion

The past few days I decided to spend some time on Stack Overflow and answer questions.  I have mostly been watching C and C++ questions.

It seems like 90% of the questions I am seeing are students asking for help with their programming homework. Most are really basic.

Is this the norm now?

Comment: There is a constant tide of crap in most popular tags on the site. That is a fact of life and something that many wonderful people work to clean up every single day. As you gain reputation on the site you will get more moderation privileges that let you help clean up the crap. What we are all looking for is those pearls that pop up every now and again. While it may seem like it isn't very often because of the sheer amount of crap coming in, there are actually a great many good quality questions asked here every day, and that is why I do it.

Comment: Is it necessarily a bad thing? Maybe it shouldn't be in the same section. We all remember what it what asking professors and TAs was like and often the quality of the replies. I also see a lot of - here do my homework for me. Well, let the punishment fit the crime - I learn by answering, thinking. If you are lazy, then oh well, you fail - here let me help you fail and help better myself and everyone else in the process.

Comment: If you set Favourite tags for the stuff you're interested in and just read the front page, a lot of the crap gets filtered out. Whoever actually reads the feeds for each tag (not me!) quickly downvotes the crap questions into oblivion, and only questions that are interesting or attracting commentary will make it onto the front page.

Comment: Weird. I spend at least 9 hours 5 days a week here and I rarely see students asking for help. Well not rarely, comparatively in a lower number than professionals. Suppose it depends on your tags. You got c & c++ and most students start with those or python. SO auto filters questions for you about those tags which contain inevitable assignment questions

Comment: Also last I checked students were welcome on SO as long as their questions showed research and effort in terms of coding. (Even though I agree they should only be given a nudge in right direction, not the code). If you think a question is low-quality and just a student slacking off, flag it for closure.

Comment: @NSNoob Yes homework questions are allowed in that we don't have a close reason for them, however it can strike a nerve when you see a true homework copy-pasta with no effort from the OP to solve their own problem. Yes these kinds of questions occur in different ratios for different tags, but I do consider those questions as part of the tide of crap (which includes all the other kinds of crap that comes in every day).

Comment: True Tiny. I usually flag or downvote those gimme-teh-codez questions. Maybe I don't get too worked up about it because my frequents tags are about iOS dev and majority of students aren't into it. But as you said, seeing someone demanding the code whether for homework or for real life scenario is pretty infuriating.

Comment: I am a Mentor on our local High School Team and am good friends with both of the teachers that teach programming.  I am sure it is difficult for them to do one-on-one with every student; so, stackoverflow is a great resource for these budding programmers.

Comment: I wrote my first computer program in 8th grade in 1971.  The district had donated a teletype to the school and none of the teachers knew what to do with it; so, the students figured it out.  Lockheed and NASA then gave us other opportunities such as a Data processing Explorer Scout Post.  Things have come a long way since then.  Lost more resources.  I was grateful for those that helped me out.

Comment: In my view, programming can be very difficult, your easy questions may be my hard questions

Comment: I started out in my new job and they wanted me to do some stuff I and they had never done before and got on stackoverflow asking questions.  That was mostly in places few students were.  The last week I had time off and decided to do some rep building by answering questions.  Since I have more experience in C/C++ I stated there and was surprised by how much of the questions were basic newbie/student/first-program-ever kind of questions.

Comment: @amuse One (of several) things I have learned about programming is that there are very little bounds on how complex a system can be.  Even a huge machine like a battleship is limited by physics and spatial reality on how many components it can have and how many can interact.  Software has very little to limit that other than our human ability to build it.

Comment: >talks sheet about others on SO >asks meta question on SO >mfw lookofdisapproval.jpg

Comment: yes. it appears to be the case, unfortuntely - got to keep the page views up

Comment: I just found this discussion from 2009 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is the time of the year for it, November is when they get their end-of-semester programming assignments.  Lasts for about 6 weeks, heaviest in the weekend.  So your timing is a bit unfortunate.

There is another bubble that starts in the middle of April, the second semester.  Different from the November bubble, more spread through the week and also the time that they start considering the exact same thing you are doing, trying to gain rep to make the resume look good.

Actual numbers are not near 90%, beware of the strong mental multiplier effect of poor posts.  Nothing like reading 5 lousy questions in a row to make you realize you've lost half an hour of your life with nothing to show for it.  And to consider posting a meta question next :)  The uptick in November of last year was about 8%, the April uptick was about 10.5%.  Not evenly spread however, only certain [tags] get the increase.

Absolute numbers are high, that's about a thousand questions every day.  Very hard to still deal with them, SO is already quite overwhelmed without the bi-yearly spikes.  I guestimate the ability to effectively curate Q+A at about 5000 questions per day, it is over double that number.

The Christmas break will be next, back to normalcy in early January.

Answer (score 9):

You're missing the point. We really *don't* care if it's homework or not as long as it meets the standards of Stack Overflow.

The [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) includes a very detailed sections on what questions should be asked in Stack Overflow. I don't see any problem with helping others even in their homework as long as they demonstrate understanding of the problem and don't ask for a solution - but then the question doesn't meet the standards and it'll be closed.

<sup>BTW, I don't see that 90% of the posts are homework-related.</sup>

Comment: It was just my experience in the C/C++ section.  I was curious about what others thought.  I will also become more familiar with the contents of the Help Center.

Comment: @markshancock 90% is just a made up number though; made up numbers don't work too well when trying to make a point. "The majority" would be a better way to say it from your own perspective.

Comment: Maybe "90% of the time I feel like 100% of all questions are about homework". (Or doesn't that add up?)

Answer (score 4):

Homework questions are questions like any other. If they are well asked, and follow our format for questions, then they are welcome here and often upvoted. The purpose is to make this site a great QA repository, and for that the quality of the questions is relevant, no where they come from.

Now, most homework questions tend to be poor, but we have mechanisms for dealing with that.

Comment: And the ones that aren't poor are still duplicates of duplicates :)

Comment: @Gimby mostly, but not always. Once in a blue moon there is a decent, non-duplicate and interesting homework question.

Comment: ^^^ lol, you fell for that one:)  Now, I have to ask 'give an example' :)

Comment: @MartinJames second that :) Not because I don't believe it, but because I really really really want to see such an amazing question.

Comment: @Gimby not that it really matters much, since we both know that, for every 'decent, non-duplicate and interesting homework question', there are hundreds of instances of trash from idle deadbeats who can't be bothered to search SO and have barely enough computer skills to copypasta.

Comment: ..or are outright liars, eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33983643/c-array-input-integers-separated-by-a-comma-and-semi-colon

Comment: @MartinJames That is usually the starting line of many slackers. "I have searched a lot but I couldn't find anything.......how can I print a variable in c++"? xD

Comment: Yeah - I've started asking for a couple links and.or the Google search string they used.  Often seems to result in deafening silence from OP.

Comment: @MartinJames almost only slackers use "I've searched everywhere but..." because absolutely no you didn't, and thats not even the point.

Comment: @Magisch I upvoted your answer, what more do you want?  :)   One aspect is that homework questions that are 'well asked, and follow our format for questions' are less-than-well presented, numerically, lately.  Some might say that, in round numbers, the count is 0 ;)

Comment: @MartinJames I don't want anything from you, I was making a situational quip on your comment :D

Comment: @MartinJames I took some time to edit that example you posted into some semblance of shape, if only to have it be a signpost and not an example on how to make people's blood boil.

Comment: @Magisch Now I have to go explain to myself why I didn't edit it, but rather chose to be annoyed and walk away. Lessons are being learned here.

Comment: Actually, some of them are quite funny:)  This obviously-homework question contains the sentence:'This is not a homework question'.   'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33990225/what-will-be-the-behavior-of-a-shared-memory-location-in-a-multi-core-system'